# How to get a line break in a title on the page head?

Tags: header-footer, line-breaking, titles, amsart

I am writing a document using the `amsart` and the title is just very long.
Now I wonder, how I could get a linebreak such that it would not overfill the heade of each page. I tried `\protect\\\` but this did not work. Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\title[An annoyingly long title that almost makes me \protect\\ cry and I do not see how to fit it into the head so the question is what I can do?]{An annoyingly long title that almost makes me cry and I do not see how to fit it into the head so the question is what I can do?}
{\maketitle}
\lipsum
\lipsum[3-56]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Some improvements at Herbert's answer:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand{\mylongtitle}[1]{%
  \ifodd\value{page}%
    \protect\parbox{0.97\linewidth}{#1}\hfill%
  \else%
    \hfill\protect\parbox{0.97\linewidth}{#1}%
  \fi%
}

\headsep=1cm
\calclayout

\begin{document}

\title[\mylongtitle{An annoyingly long title that almost makes me cry and I
do not see how to fit it into the head so the question is what I can do?}]
{An annoyingly long title that almost makes me cry and I do not see how to
fit it into the head so the question is what I can do?}
\maketitle
\lipsum
\lipsum[3-56]
\end{document}
```

[image]

I've defined a new command `\mylongtitle` to be used inside the optional argument of `\title` that ensures correct spacing on odd and even pages.

Also I've added

```
\headsep=1cm
```

to balance the distance between header and text (better not to use `geometry` since it messes up `amsart` settings). `\calclayout` after it recalculates the page layout.

Comment: +1 for making this work even when a (short) author name is present, and for warning not to use `geometry`.  (but i agree with @Herbert's comment that a one-line title heading is preferable.) but why is `{\maketitle}` in braces? (perhaps to avoid undefining some elements?) and a comment: the first page is significantly longer than the other pages; this is partly because 11pt text doesn't provide an integral number of lines and there's no vertical stretch to compensate, but also because `\calclayout` hasn't been rerun to adjust the page length after you increased `\headsep`.

Comment: @barbara Thanks. `\maketitle` was in braces because I didn't notice it... I, too, would't use such long title headings. In regards of the first page, the text is simply a little shifted down as in other pages, or am I missing something?

Comment: on the first page, i'm pretty sure there's some stretch (i didn't check), so `\flushbottom` is applied, and the enlargement of `\headsep` without recalculating the whole does increase the page length (look at `\calclayout` in `amsclass.dtx`).  since `\flushbottom` won't apply on non-first pages (no stretch), the discrepancy becomes more obvious.

Comment: @barbara `\calclayout` added!

Answer (score 4):

use a `\parbox`:

```
\title[\hfill\protect\parbox{0.975\linewidth}{An annoyingly 
         long title that almost makes me\\ cry and I do not see how to fit it 
         into the head so the question is what I can do?}]{An annoyingly 
         long title that almost makes me cry and I do not see how to fit it 
         into the head so the question is what I can do?}
```

Comment: That is already great. However the problem that I get when I use your solution is that it completly messes up with the distance from the header to the text..

Comment: sure, that's the reason why you should use a _one line_ alternative heading and not the long one.

Comment: Ok, I see. Thanx!